# How to construct the following model in R

Tags: r, autoregressive-models

i would like to construct the following model in R
`Yt = A+B*Xt+Nt`
where Xt is time and B is the trend coefficient and `Nt = φNt-1+et φ`first order auto-correlation of the residuals and et white noise.

I have tried to use the gls function as follow

```
fm <- gls(Y~1+T,correlation=corAR1(value=acf(Y,na.action=na.pass)$acf[2],form=~1),na.action=na.omit)
```

but i am not totally sure if it models the residuals the way i would like.

Furthermore, i would like to get in my results the time series of the Nt and et, so as to calculate the variance of Nt (σΝ). I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resid to get what you want. The complete code

```
et=rnorm(100)
tt=1:length(et)
Nt=et[1]
for (i in 2:length(et))Nt[i]=0.6*Nt[i-1]+et[i]
Yt=100+3*tt+Nt
fm <- gls(Yt~1+tt,correlation=corAR1(value=acf(Yt,na.action=na.pass)$acf[2],form=~1),na.action=na.omit)
summary(fm)
res=resid(fm)
plot(ts(res))
lines(ts(Nt),col=3)
acf(resid(fm))
acf(Nt)
```